# using UNION together with WITH statement in SQL

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I have a location table. Each location stored in this table as a tree. Records can be a sublocation of any other location and so on. 
In my location table, I execute the following tsql to produce all locations with their sublocations

```
WITH LocationTree AS (
    SELECT L.* FROM Location L
                UNION
    SELECT L.* FROM LocationTree LT, Location L where L.ParentLocationID = LT.LocationID
        )

SELECT * FROM LocationTree
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Recursive common table expression 'LocationTree' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.
```

The error says that i have to use **UNION ALL** insead of **UNION** but **UNION ALL** returns repeated rows. I want to select distinct rows like when using UNION only.

How can i use **UNION** keyword within a **WITH** statement in SQL?

Comment: just wondering..what about a different name for recursive query, i mean instead of LocationTree, which is also name of your table?

Comment: @bonsvr You think my query is wrong? I found that example on net so i am not so sure about it. If you see any mistake, can you please tell me to correct my query?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because your CTE is named the same as one of your tables:

```
WITH LT AS (
    SELECT L.* FROM Location L
                UNION
    SELECT L.* FROM LocationTree LT, Location L where L.ParentLocationID = LT.LocationID
        )
SELECT * FROM LT
```

works fine for me

Comment: I dont want to leave it to outer select. Thats why i insist on solving it in WITH statement

Comment: There is no table LocationTree in my db. I store parentID and locationID in same table named Location.

Comment: This is the answer.  I had thought SQL could disambiguate between cte table names and real tables.  I was doing the same, but with different case on the names.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` and `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM LocationTree` in the outer select.

Comment: I dont want to leave it to outer select. Thats why i insist on solving it in WITH statement.